# How to pass correct urls to iframe page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, location

The URLs like below are supported on my site:

```
(1) http://mysite.example.com/section/ - main page
(2) http://mysite.example.com/section/#page2
(3) http://mysite.example.com/section/surname-name-middlename/
(4) http://mysite.example.com/section/surname-name-middlename/#page2
(5) http://mysite.example.com/section/add
```

Now I am trying to show my site as iframe on another site. That site supports `setLocation` and `onLocationChanged` methods to define hash and react when hash is changed accordingly.

I've defined `setLocation` for all pages, no problem here. So, links above at 3rd party site look like below:

```
(1) http://3rdpartysite.com/mypage
(2) http://3rdpartysite.com/mypage#page2
(3) http://3rdpartysite.com/mypage#surname-name-middlename
(4) http://3rdpartysite.com/mypage#surname-name-middlename,page2
(5) http://3rdpartysite.com/mypage#add
```

But now I am trying to implement correct `onLocationChanged` behaviour.

`section` is common part for all pages.

I've tried to do the following at the main page (and not supporting option (4) above):

```
// location here is everything after # in url: http://3rdpartysite.com/mypage#...
function onLocationChanged(location) { 
  if (location.indexOf('page')>-1) {
    window.location.href = '#'+location;
  } else if (location == 'add') {
      window.location.href = window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/add';
    } else if (location != '') {
        window.location.href = window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/'+location+'/';
      }
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code working properly at the main page:

```
function onLocationChanged(loc) {
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    if (loc.indexOf('page') > -1 && loc.indexOf(',page') == -1) {
        window.location.href = '#' + loc;
    } else if (loc == 'add') {
        window.location.href = url + 'add';
    } else if (loc != '' && loc.indexOf(',page') > -1) {
        window.location.href = url + '' + loc.split(',', 2)[0] + '/#' + loc.split(',', 2)[1];
    } else if (loc != '') {
        window.location.href = url + '' + loc + '/';
    }
}
```

and here is the code for other pages (without option (4) support):

```
function onLocationChanged(loc) {
  var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/',3)[1] + '/';
  if (loc.indexOf('page')>-1) {
    window.location.href = url + '#' + loc;
  } else if (loc == 'add') {
      window.location.href = url + 'add';
    } else if (loc != '') {
        window.location.href = url + '' + loc + '/';
      }
}
```

Don't know how to make it common.